# Evolution of gas during chemical reaction

Tags: experimental-chemistry

Why is it that whenever hydrogen gas is produced in a reaction, it comes out in the form of tiny bubbles, but whenever Carbon dioxide is produced it comes out in the form of a brisk effervescence like lather?

Comment: Biological, thermal, electrolytic, or simple chemical reactions can all produce these gasses.  Can you specify which reactions?

Answer (score 1):

Likely, any difference you've observed is due to the high solubility of $\ce{CO2}$ in water... it allows accumulation of enough dissolved gas to nucleate and form large bubbles, as in seltzer. BTW, $\ce{Na}$ or $\ce{K}$ etc. do *not* make tiny bubbles when put in water.